# How to extract file name from shell command from a ansible play

Tags: mysql, shell, ansible

I am taking a db dump as follows:

```
- name: create backup of the EMS database
  shell: " mysqldump --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --hex-blob --complete-insert -h {{groups.db_name[0]}} -u {{ db_user }} -p{{ db_password }} {{ db_name }} > {{ vars.inventory_dir }}/../{{ db_name}}_backup-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}.sql"
  register: db_backup
```

now if you notice the shell command at the end i dump the mysql with a date-time appended as `{{ db_name}}_backup-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}.sql`

How can i use only this dynamic part in my next play ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you first store the filename as a fact:

```
- set_fact:
    mysql_dump_file: "{{ db_name }}_backup-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}.sql"
```

Then in the dump task and all following tasks where you need the filename you use that fact: `{{ mysql_dump_file }}`

```
- name: create backup of the EMS database
  shell: "mysqldump --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --hex-blob --complete-insert -h {{ groups.db_name[0] }} -u {{ db_user }} -p{{ db_password }} {{ db_name }} > {{ vars.inventory_dir }}/../{{ mysql_dump_file }}"
  register: db_backup
```

Comment: does this remains same in all subsequent tasks? i.e `mysql_dump_file` because it has the ansible_date_time stuff?

Comment: The fact is stored for the current playbook execution, so all subsequent tasks have the same value for `mysql_dump_file`. If you even need the same value for subsequent playbook executions, you can look into [caching facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching).